# Sending data back from php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I tried [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) tutorial to send/retrieve data from my mysql database, using ajax and php.
This is the ajax part:

```
                <script>
                    function showUser(str) {
                      if (str=="") {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                        return;
                      }
                      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                      }
                      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                      }
                      xmlhttp.open("GET","suchen_ma.php?id="+str,true);
                      xmlhttp.send();
                    }
                </script>
```

The .php file looks like this:

```
<?php

//Connection Details
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$hostname = 'localhost';
$databasename = 'plzdb';


$id             = ($_GET['id']);

//Connection-string
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$databasename);

//SQL Query
$sql = "SELECT per_vorname,per_nachname from plz_person
        WHERE per_id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['per_vorname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['per_nachname'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The data is formatted within the php file, but I want to send the "raw" data back to the html and display it inside a list and format it with css. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this

Comment: unfortunately, I don't understand you question... what do you mean by "raw" data? what data and how do you want to send it back?

Comment: And what is the problem? Did you got any error? Is this working correctly and you just don't know how to continue, as the tutorial ended here?

Comment: It is working, the php finds the entrys and they are shown inside the html, but the formating happens inside the .php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give back the data as JSON:

```
$sql = "SELECT per_vorname,per_nachname from plz_person
        WHERE per_id = " . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $id);
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $persons[] = array(
        "vorname" => $row['per_vorname'],
        "per_nachname" => $row['per_nachname']
    );
}
echo json_encode($persons);
```

and then create a loop in javascript, to build the HTML.

NOTE: Avoid sql injection by escaping your string.